# Вывод в консоль в начало и в конец строки

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, реально ли в java выводить в консоль цифры/строку, в правую часть консоли, в фиксированный столбец?

```
[1.1.2015/INFO] MY MESSAGE1                         1
[1.1.2015/INFO] MY MESSAGE TWO                      2
[1.1.2015/INFO] MY MESSAGE THREE                    3
[1.1.2015/INFO] MY MESSAGE FOR                      4
[1.1.2015/INFO] MY MESSAGE FIVE BLA BLA             5
```

Comment: Уточните плз, а какой то логгер-фреймворк уже используется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужен [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). Вот какой-то [материал](http://study-java.ru/uroki-java/formatirovanie-chisel-i-texta-v-java/) на эту тему.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String message = "adfdfs";
    int counter = 3;
    String logMessage = String.format("[1.1.2015/INFO] %-40s %d", message, counter);
    System.out.println(logMessage);
}
```

Но как правильно заметил @flybox, если Вы пытаетесь написать свой фреймворк для логирования, то не тратьте время, их уже достаточно. Потратьте полчаса на изучение [существующих решений](http://habrahabr.ru/post/247647/).